# Is there a way to use the compareTo() method for a data set, without iterating through each element of the set?

Tags: java, data-structures

I am wondering if there is a way to use compareTo() without having to iterate through each string element in the data set, I'm pretty sure this is not possible using arrays, but is there a data structure that is capable of working in that way?

See example below for clearer explanation:

```
public static int PronounDetector(String [] pronouns)
{
    String [] you = {"you", "You"};             
    for (int i = 0; i < pronouns.length; i++)   
    {
        if (pronouns[i].compareTo(you) == 0)
        //Is there a way for compareTo to run through 
        //the entire String data set without having to make 
        //it iterate through each element using a for loop?
        {
            return 2;
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: I understand that no matter what the program will iterate through the data set, (how else will it find a match?), I am just looking to see if there is a way to do it without me actually having the physically type in the for loop.

Comment: Worst-case scenario will *always* lead to search of entire data-structure. So, No. its not possible.

Comment: Pretty sure if you want to compare something to every element, you're gonna have to iterate through every element _somehow_. Also, I don't think your code would even compile...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The must be meet two conditions if you want to skip some data during search processing.

1. The data must be related.
2. The data must be organized.

You can improve your search, by sorting the array and then compare from the middle. 
Then in each step you will reduce element that must be compare by half.

Instead of array you can used TreeMap, that will store the data in tree structure to have same result.

Code example:

```
public static boolean contains(String[] array, String key) {

        Objects.requireNonNull(array,"The array must not be null");
        Objects.requireNonNull(array,"The key must not be null");

        String[] copy = array.clone();
        Arrays.sort(copy);

        return Arrays.binarySearch(copy, key) != -1;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you don't have to "double iterate" (even though that's exactly what happens under the hood) you can convert the array `you` to a string and search it using `contains()`:

```
    String youStr = Arrays.deepToString(you);
    System.out.println(youStr.contains(pronouns[0])); // prints 'true'
```